# Entering login info with AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I am using AppleScript to enter login information and after the script enters the information into the password field and a "keystroke return" is performed the form tells me my password is incorrect even though I am sure that I am passing the correct password in my script.

Does anyone know why this is occurring?

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    open location "https://thewebsite.com"
end tell

delay 10
clickClassName("login", 0)
delay 2

tell application "Safari"
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari"
        keystroke tab
        keystroke "MyPassword"
        keystroke return
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: we might need some information about what you are doing before we can help you. so far, you have said nothing useful

Comment: give an snippet of your code, and probably remove the javascript tag, since I don't see how this question is related to javascript. people will probably start downvoting your question until you give more info.

Comment: If you want help debugging code, then your question should conform to [How to create a Minimal, Complete,and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: How are you sure that `"MyPassword"` is the correct password? Have you manually copied and pasted it from Script Editor to the Login Password Field of the webpage and it works? Have you tested this code against some other login scenarios and it works?

Comment: There is nothing Complete and Verifiable with the code example you've posted! 1. It contains a bogus URL. 2. It contain a _handler_ that's not defined. 3. How are we supposed to test your code!? You need to post a working URL that we can create an account at and use our own password to see if we get the same results. That's part of how debugging code works, if we can replicate your results (the Verifiable part of MCVE) then we have something to try and debug against. Otherwise, what do you expect us to do with what you've posted so far!?

Answer (score 1):

```
tell application "Safari"   
    activate   
    open location "https://thewebsite.com"   
end tell   

delay 10   
clickClassName("login", 0)   
delay 2   

tell application "Safari"   
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari"   
        keystroke tab   
delay 0.2   
        keystroke "MyPassword"   
0.5 -- you need the delay because it does not type instantly and the password is probably cut short.  
        keystroke return   
    end tell   
end tell
```

Comment: You said, "you need the delay because it does not type instantly and the password is probably cut short". Actually, System Events processes keystroke commands asynchronous, so there is no real need to place a delay as the typing of the password will finish before typing return. You can test this in Script Editor using a very long string followed by return, the entire string will be typed before return.